# Making a matrix of inputs from user defined inputs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, css-grid

I am trying to do the following in React:

1. User inputs rows and columns
2. A grid is created in react of blank inputs, displayed as a grid with the correct dimensions.

So far I have the following. Here I am assuming that the rows and columns that the user has input is 3 for both for brevity:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  // create a 3x3 matrix with some blank inputs as values values
  const matrix = Array.apply(null, Array(9)).map(function (x, i) {
    return <input></input>;
  });

  return <div className="App">{matrix}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Now this just gives me output that looks as follows:

[image]

Could someone please give me some ideas as to how can turn the above into a 3x3 grid? I want it to eventually adjust based on what row and column values that the user provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are creating a basic array of 9 elements. The most logical way to break it into rows and columns would likely be to create 3 arrays containing 3 input elements each, then separating each group of 3 inputs within something like a `<div>` so they are rendered on separate lines.

One solution is something like

```
const matrix = Array.apply(null, Array(3))
  .map(function (x, i) {
    const col = Array.apply(null, Array(3))
      .map(function (y, j) {
        return <input></input>
      });

    return <div>{col}</div>;
  });
```

As you refine the solution, it may be best to extract the row/column counts to their own variables.

That should get you through the basics of the problem. From there, it may be cleaner to render these as cells in a table, etc.

Feel free to take a look at [grid layouts](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) which may be in line with what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mike, for a noob this is super helpful. I will try and read more about this css grid!